# How to implement you own custom DirectShow renderer?

Tags: c++, c, directshow, renderer, samplegrabber

How to implement you own custom DirectShow renderer that could work a-la or instead of SampleGrabber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.gdcl.co.uk/AppFilter.zip

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking into BaseClasses from PlatformSDK. There are C++ classes for Media Renderer. You can use them.

Comment: yeah the SDK has several "samples" in it